vbs - check if a Remote Desktop Connection was connected
We have a script that runs RDC to connect to a remote machine. Issue is that it sometimes takes multiple tries to connect. The first few tries will often get

until it gets to the expected password prompt

So I would like to have the script to check the response window, and if it's the "can't connect" response, loop again until it connects. But I can't figure out how to check that.
An indirect way may be to take advantage of the fact that the "can't connect" window does not appear in the taskbar, while the initial "connecting" window, as well as the password prompt, do. So if I could have a loop that checks every 2 seconds if "Remote Desktop Connection" appears in the taskbar, that would solve the problem. But I don't know if that can be done.

VBS isn’t powerful enough to do what you want
